# Removing the my account-dashboard and redirect to another endpoint like downloads

Tags: woocommerce

I don't want the customers to get linked to the myaccount-dashboard with the annoying Hello xy, from here you can blabla, when they click on "My Account".

Is there an **endpoint** for the my account dashboard? I didn't find it on the backend in woocommerce>Settings>Accounts...

What's working is: I set up a **custom link under menu/navigation**... called it "My Account" and set the link to /myaccount/downloads for example.
So, when customers are logged in and they click on My Account, they get redirected to Downloads.

I'm wondering, is there another way to get rid of the dashboard?
Or a redirect solution? Thanks.

Comment: Does it work if you just disable/delete the My Account page?

Comment: thanks, you got me thinking: unfortunately, there is nothing in the my-account.php page that I can edit. The first .php that is loaded automatically is dashboard.php. Yes, I deleted/renamed this file and I get a blank my-account page with the sub-menues I want on the left side...

Comment: haha...or: I delete the dashboard.php file... duplicate the downloads.php file, rename the duplicate dashboard and I get rid of the dashboard and the annoying message "Hello... from here you can...." after all and get the customer straight to the download sub-menu of my-account :) still have to check if this works...

Answer (score 4):

Remove it using below function. change downloads to your requirement.

```
function custom_my_account_menu_items( $items ) {
    unset($items['downloads']);
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'custom_my_account_menu_items' );
```

Comment: Sorry for above answer, it wont work. 

Instead, use code from below link. it basically does take menu items as mentioned in it

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-remove-submenu-on-my-account-page-for-admin-shop-manager/

Comment: You can remove your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Looking more closely it seems like there are a handful of ways to do this. Take a look at the [`my-account.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.13/templates/myaccount/my-account.php) template. You could override this, but I found that if you remove the `woocommerce_account_content` hook, you get a deprecation notice and WooCommerce thinks you have an outdated template and adds the content anyway.

Looking at the template you will see two hooks. The side menu navigation is added to the `woocommerce_account_navigation` and the content is added to `woocommerce_account_content` function. You can remove the defaults from their hooks and add back just the downloads content.

```
function so_41983566_remove_account_dadshboard(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_account_navigation', 'woocommerce_account_navigation' );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_account_content', 'woocommerce_account_content' );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_account_content', 'so_41983566_download_content' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_navigation', 'so_41983566_remove_account_dadshboard', 1 );

function so_41983566_download_content(){
    do_action( 'woocommerce_account_downloads_endpoint' );
}
```

Or [`woocommerce_account_content()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.13/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L2105-L2130) and [`woocommerce_account_navigation()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.13/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L2132-L2140) are both pluggable functions and you can just define new versions in your theme/plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This link explains everything:

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Customising-account-page-tabs

1. First you need to create an endpoint:

   ```
   function my_custom_endpoints() {
       add_rewrite_endpoint( 'my-custom-endpoint', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
   }
   add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_endpoints' );    
   function my_custom_query_vars( $vars ) {
       $vars[] = 'my-custom-endpoint';    
       return $vars;
   }
   add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_custom_query_vars', 0 );
   ```
2. Then create the menu item:

   ```
   function my_custom_my_account_menu_items( $items ) {
       $logout = $items['customer-logout'];
       unset( $items['customer-logout'] );
       $items['my-custom-endpoint'] = __( 'My Custom Endpoint', 'woocommerce' );
       $items['customer-logout'] = $logout;
       return $items;
   }
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'my_custom_my_account_menu_items' );
   ```
3. Add content to the endpoint

   ```
   function my_custom_endpoint_content() {
       echo '<p>Hello World!</p>';
   }
   add_action( 'woocommerce_account_my-custom-endpoint_endpoint', 'my_custom_endpoint_content' );
   ```